# Label de boton se sobrepone al mismo HTML y CSS

Tags: html, css

Comencé hace poco a hacer front-end y estoy desarrollando el login que se puede apreciar en el snippet.
Mi problema es que el botón redondo para recordar el login se me sobrepone junto al `label` del mismo.

```css
body, html {
  margin:0;
  font-family:Arial;
}

.loginForm {
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  -webkit-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  -moz-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  -o-transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
  position:absolute;
}

input,button {
  outline:none;
  padding:10px;
  border:1px solid #c6c6c6c1;
}

.center {
    width: 10%;
    height: 10%;
    size: 20%;
}

.roundedCheckbox {
    position: relative;
    margin-bottom: 2%;
}

.roundedCheckbox label {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px;
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #fcfff4;
    background: #f5f5f5 40%;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 100%;
    font-family: Bahnschrift;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 0.55rem;
    color: #00C9FF;
}

.roundedCheckbox label:after {
    content: '';
    width: 9px;
    height: 5px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 5px;
    left: 4px;
    border: 3px solid rgb(8, 250, 0);
    border-top: none;
    border-right: none;
    background: transparent;
    opacity: 0;
    transform: rotate(-45deg);
}

.roundedCheckbox label:hover::after {
    opacity: 0.3;
}

.roundedCheckbox input[type=checkbox] {
    visibility: hidden;
}

.roundedCheckbox input[type=checkbox]:checked+label:after {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Techcoy Log in</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/style.css">
    <link rel="icon" href="./img/Logo.ico">
</head>
<body>
    <!-- Formulario Log-in -->
    <div class="loginForm">
    <form action="" method="get" autocomplete="off">
        <h3>Iniciar Sesión</h3>
        <p><input type="email" name="username" class="inputAlign1" placeholder="Email"></p>
        <p><input type="password" name="password" class="inputAlign2" placeholder="Password"></p>
      <div class="roundedCheckbox">
       <input type="checkbox" value="None" id="roundedCheckbox" name="check" unchecked /><label for="roundedCheckbox">RECORDARME</label>
      </div>
        <input type="submit" class="btn btn-LogIn" value="Ingresar">
      </form>
    </div>
 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema puntual es que la etiqueta tiene un ancho fijo de 20px, y el texto que está dentro de ella está alineado a la izquierda, por eso las primeras letras de la etiqueta quedan montadas en el fondo circular.

La solución a eso sería indentar el texto dentro de la etiqueta, pero no usando `padding` (cambiaría el ancho de la etiqueta), sino con `text-indent`:

```
.roundedCheckbox label {
    width: 20px;
    height: 20px; 
    text-indent: 28px; /* -> mueve el texto a la derecha */
    line-height: 20px; /* -> para la alineación vertical */
    cursor: pointer;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: #fcfff4;
    background: #f5f5f5 40%;
    box-shadow: inset 0px 1px 1px white, 0px 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 100%;
    font-family: Bahnschrift;
    font-weight: 600;
    font-size: 0.55rem;
    color: #00C9FF;
}
```

**Soporte**: `text-indent` tiene soporte básico en todos los navegadores principales, incluso desde IE6 (https://caniuse.com/css-text-indent). Tiene otras características avanzadas, pero casi ningún navegador las soporta todavía, de todas formas este ejemplo debe funcionar en cualquier navegador actual.

Comment: Muchisimas gracias, en 2 lineas de codigo me solucionaste 2 horas buscando por internet. Saludos!